# Is there a comfortable part of Venus's upper atmosphere?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, temperature, venus

I know the surface of Venus is very hot, but that it gets cooler the higher you go in the atmosphere.  I have heard that there is a section in the atmosphere of Venus that might be somewhat habitable even, that where it is about 1 atmosphere, the temperature is slightly over 100 F.  Not really comfortable, but possibly livable temperature wise (likely with some cooling mechanism).  However, I recently heard that near the poles, the atmosphere is extremely cold: http://www.iflscience.com/space/death-plunge-venus-spacecraft-reveals-hottest-planet-not-so-hot/

Does this mean that at the height where the atmospheric pressure is 1 atmosphere, and somewhere between the pole and the equator would lie a comfortable zone of 72 F?  "Extra credit" for suggesting / providing reasoning for a likely latitude where this condition would exist (if it does).  If this does exist, it might make an ideal place for a blimp like sky colony.  I am considering adding this to my Planetary Settlers video game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a layer of Venus's atmosphere that has bright white clouds, a white sky, no acid rain, 1 atm pressure, a warm tropical climate and 0.9 gravities...

It is the cloud layers between 50 and 70km altitude above the ground.

[image: http://faculty.virginia.edu/skrutskie/ASTR1210/notes/venus.html]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I am curious at that altitude, if there is a certain latitude where it would be comfortable (72 F) at 1 atmosphere.  I hear it is actually cold at the poles in the upper atmosphere on Venus.

Comment: Very strong winds (300-400km/h) ensure good mixing of the warm and cold air, so there shouldn't be the strong temperature differences between equator and poles we see on Earth or Mars.

Comment: You should provide a source to your chart.   Other than that, nice answer.    An Oxygen balloon could float in Venus' CO2 atmosphere, and CO2 could be used to grow plants.  It may be the most potentially habitable region in the solar system other than Earth, but high winds, some very acidic rain probably gets through and 100% thick cloud cover all the time (no visible stars, sunrise or sunset) and it wouldn't be great for solar collectors either and certain death below might not making a popular destination.  Not sure but there might be lightning too.

Comment: Hard to see any way a layer of cloud could exist sandwiched between two layers with sulphuric acid content and not itself have sulphuric acid (at the very least moving between layers).  So I don't think this could qualify as "comfortable".

Comment: I’d be happy to upvote if you add a reference or source.